# Java Database and ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, database, class, resultset

First post here, so I hope I get the etiquette right.

Working on a project for a programming course, where we've been given certain parameters that make things a little awkward (because there are better ways to do it I know).

I have a database created, and populated with data, I can get the data I need from it, but the way I'm doing it is clunky and rubbish. So I'm looking for a better way.

The two classes I'm dealing with at this time are StockData.class and CheckStock.class.

StockData.class is the database handler...

in which I have the following:

```
    public static String getPrice(String key) {
        try {

            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM StockDB WHERE stockID = '" + key + "'");
            if (res.next()) { // there is a result
                return res.getString(3);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
public static ResultSet getID() 
{
    try
        {
        ResultSet keyList = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT stockID FROM StockDB");
        {
        return keyList;
        }                
                    }
                catch (SQLException e)
            {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
            }
```

(There are other similar ones for each column)

I'm calling these methods from CheckStock with the following:

```
        key = "11";
        debug.append(" " + newline);
        debug.append("   " + StockData.getName(key));
        debug.append("   " + StockData.getPrice(key)); 
        debug.append("   " + StockData.getQuantity(key));
```

As you can see I'm hand typing my stockID - which is a string.. which doesn't make the system expandable (I'd have to add in a whole new set of keys by hand for any new items.

In order to use the Database to supply the keys I had tried to use the following

```
          ResultSet stockIDList = StockData.getID();
          while (stockIDList.next())
               {
                key = (stockIDList.getNString(1));
                debug.append("   " + StockData.getName(key));
                debug.append("   " + StockData.getPrice(key)); 
                debug.append("   " + StockData.getQuantity(key));                  
               }
```

But that spits out all sorts of SQL errors.

I'm assuming I'm missing something very simple, or that there's a much better way of doing it.

I've been trying to get my head around this little problem all day with the help of an internet and the oracle pages on ResultSet but I can't for the life of me work out why it's not working.

Thank you in advance of any help.

Myranda

Comment: *"But that spits out all sorts of SQL errors."* Good errors represent answers to your problem. Copypasting a single error into a decent search engine will usually already give a lot of clues. When you ignore them you're basically shooting yourself in the foot. Don't do that and include them unmodified in the question in case you're not capable of interpreting them or finding clues.

Comment: I got the error message:   java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is off.   but I couldn't see how to apply the solution I found to my code...

Comment: Have you tried [copypasting it into a decent search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22java.sql.SQLException%3A+ResultSet+not+open.+Operation+'next'+not+permitted.+Verify+that+autocommit+is+off%22) for clues?

Comment: Yes, I copypasted it into google, but I couldn't work out how to implement what people were saying... after a full day staring at the problem I couldn't see the wood for the trees...

Answer (score 0):

I have (through trial and error) found a work around.

From what I could see of search results I should have been using final statments to close out the queries, but I couldn't seem to get them to fit without netBeans throwing exclamation marks all over the place...

So I used an individual statment name for each field that I was querying...

```
    public static double getPrice(String key) {
        try {
            Statement stmtPrice;
            stmtPrice = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmtPrice.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM StockDB WHERE stockID = '" + key + "'");
            if (res.next()) { 
                return res.getDouble(3);
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static int getQuantity(String key) {
        try {
            Statement stmtQty;
            stmtQty = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmtQty.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM StockDB WHERE stockID = '" + key + "'");
            if (res.next()) { 
                return res.getInt(4); 
                    } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Then this was called using the following

```
        ResultSet stockIDList = StockData.getID();
        while (stockIDList.next())
            {
                key = (stockIDList.getString(1));
                stockID.append(" " + key + newline);
                stockDescription.append("   " + StockData.getName(key) + newline);
                stockPrice.append("   " + StockData.getPrice(key) + newline); 
                stockQuantity.append("   " + StockData.getQuantity(key) + newline);
                double price = StockData.getPrice(key);
                int quantity = StockData.getQuantity(key);
                double total = price * quantity;
                String stringTotal = String.valueOf(total);
                stockTotalValue.append(" " + stringTotal + newline);
            }
```

No doubt someone will be horrified by the clunky code I've used, but it seems to be doing the job, so for now I'll take clunky over non-functional.

Thank you all for your time.

Myranda